# Remove closest label style

Tags: jquery

I have 3 labels when I click on label bg color need to be added.and color removed for other labels.how to do it?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.agentBtn').click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      'background': '#2196F3',
      'color': '#fff'
    });
    $(this).closest().find('label').removeAttr('style');
  });
  $('.ownerBtn').click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      'background': '#2196F3',
      'color': '#fff'
    });
    $(this).closest('label').removeAttr('style');
  });
  $('.otherBtn').click(function() {
    $(this).css({
      'background': '#2196F3',
      'color': '#fff'
    });
    $(this).closest().find('label').removeAttr('style');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="btn agentBtn">
  <input type="radio" id="agent" name="advanced-search-beds" checked >Agent
</label>
<label class="btn ownerBtn">
 <input type="radio" id="owner" name="advanced-search-beds">Owner
</label>
<label class="btn otherBtn">
 <input type="radio" id="other" name="advanced-search-beds">Other
</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your other labels are siblings, you can use the `siblings` method from jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css({'background':'#2196F3', 'color':'#fff'});
        $this.siblings("label").removeAttr('style');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="btn">
    <input type="radio" id="agent" name="advanced-search-beds" checked>Agent
</label>
<label class="btn">
    <input type="radio" id="owner" name="advanced-search-beds">Owner
</label>
<label class="btn">
    <input type="radio" id="other" name="advanced-search-beds">Other
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

you shouldnt use `$(this).closest('label').removeAttr('style');` because ure applying to the "clicked" one. u need remove it to all labels excluding the clicked one. for example:

```
$(this).css({'background':'#2196F3', 'color':'#fff'});
$('label').not(this).removeAttr('style');
```

look at my example: https://jsfiddle.net/zLsnatck/

Comment: I had the same idea, though I think using `closest` or `siblings` is better, because there will probably be different labels in the form that may collide.

Comment: yes, siblings is an option ive used too, but his code is very basic and he wants remove all others labels css, not only the closest, anyways to not have problems with another labels in anothers sides, he should add parent classes only for the targets

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('.agentBtn').click(function(){
                    $(this).closest('div').find('label').removeAttr('style');
                    $(this).css({'background':'#2196F3', 'color':'#fff'});
                    
                });
                $('.ownerBtn').click(function(){
                    $(this).closest('div').find('label').removeAttr('style');
                    $(this).css({'background':'#2196F3', 'color':'#fff'});
                });
                $('.otherBtn').click(function(){ 
                    $(this).closest('div').find('label').removeAttr('style');                                                                  
                    $(this).css({'background':'#2196F3', 'color':'#fff'});
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label class="btn agentBtn">
    <input type="radio" id="agent" name="advanced-search-beds" checked >Agent
  </label>
  <label class="btn ownerBtn">
    <input type="radio" id="owner" name="advanced-search-beds">Owner
  </label>
  <label class="btn otherBtn">
    <input type="radio" id="other" name="advanced-search-beds">Other
  </label>
</div>
```